# How do I get Bittorrent Sync to run automatically after a reboot?

Tags: sync, bittorrent, init

I have to enter ./btsync in the terminal every time I reboot. Then I have to open a browser and enter my username and password, kind of a pita. Do have to make or edit an init file? Yes I am new to Linux. I am using the latest version of btsync, which btw is so much faster and convenient than (expletive) Samba.

Comment: All I hear are crickets...

Comment: This ? Could wind up being my 2nd Tumbleweed Can I get an upvote?

Comment: Maybe a +5 just because

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my cron to launch it at every start-up.

1. Edit cron with `crontab -e`
2. insert a line at the end with the following command:

   ```
   @reboot /absolute/path/to/your/btsync
   ```

You might end up with a few different editors:

- Using vim/vi you would need to press `I` to enter typing mode and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to quit typing mode, then type `:wq` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save + quit
- Using nano, you can start typing immediately, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to quit